# WorkManager. How to cancel appended work?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm trying to cancel a task that hasn't started yet.

My `Worker` class code:

```
class TestWork(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
Worker(context, workerParams) {

override fun doWork(): Result {
    val data = inputData.getInt(KEY_OBJ, -1)
    runBlocking {
        for (i in 1..3){
            Log.d("MyTag", "testWork: $data")
            delay(1000)
        }
    }

    return Result.SUCCESS
}

override fun onStopped() {
    super.onStopped()
    Log.d("MyTag", "stopped")
}

companion object {
        const val KEY_OBJ = "key"
        val WORK_NAME = "name"
    }
}
```

The code sample that running 3 works and canceling second.
But second work continues.

```
    val data1 = Data.Builder()
        .putInt(TestWork.KEY_OBJ, 1)
        .build()

    val workRequest1 = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWork::class.java)
        .setInputData(data1)
        .addTag("1")
        .build()

    val data2 = Data.Builder()
        .putInt(TestWork.KEY_OBJ, 2)
        .build()

    val workRequest2 = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWork::class.java)
        .setInputData(data2)
        .addTag("2")
        .build()

    val data3 = Data.Builder()
        .putInt(TestWork.KEY_OBJ, 3)
        .build()

    val workRequest3 = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWork::class.java)
        .setInputData(data3)
        .addTag("3")
        .build()

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork(
        TestWork.WORK_NAME,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
        workRequest1
    )

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork(
        TestWork.WORK_NAME,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
        workRequest2
    )

    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork(
        TestWork.WORK_NAME,
        ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
        workRequest3
    )

    WorkManager.getInstance().cancelWorkById(workRequest2.id)
```

How to cancel second work only? While the first is executed

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you have a mistake in your cancelling line, you have to replace `cancelWorkById("2")` by `cancelAllWorkByTag("2")` because you are adding tags `.addTag("2")` to the Work.

I'm currently using WorkManager and I have tried to cancel works with tags and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`isStopped()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker?hl=SR#isStopped()) method call inside your `onWork` method

This is explained in the video presented at the Android Developer Summit. [Around minute 15 into the presentation there's a whole section on how to stop work in WorkManager that goes through these details](https://youtu.be/83a4rYXsDs0?t=922)